# Exchange with Nearby Connection API slower than classic Wifi-Direct

Tags: android, kotlin, wifi-direct, google-nearby, google-nearby-connections

When I exchange data using the Nearby Connections API, between two devices not connected to a network, and then one of them connects to the other device's Direct-Wifi network, the transfer speed is very slow.
If I use a classic Android WiFi-Direct connection instead, the transfer speed is significantly faster. Why?